# Strong formatting broken?

Tags: bug, design

I just posted a question which contains **bold** formatting in several places, and the output is not bold. Is something broken here? I even used `**bold**` above and it does not appear to have gotten any formatting treatment on Meta either.

For me on **`Chrome v62`** it renders as such:

> [image: Bold formatting Chrome 62]

Oddly enough, it seems to still apply the font weight adjustment on **`**code blocks**`**.

Comment: i see your bolded bold text bold, maybe this changed overnight?

Comment: Still not showing as such for me. Maybe it's an issue with Chrome...

Comment: im using chrome as well -> Version 61.0.3163.100 (Build officiel) (64 bits)
RELANCER

Comment: Which version are you on? I'm on 62.

Comment: Maybe that version change breaks things. Uh oh.

Comment: ill post a screenshot of what i see below

Comment: mind including a screenshot of how it is displayed in your browser =P

Comment: I can see the bold on chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Chrome 63.0.3239.132 (on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2) with all extensions turned off and I don't see the bolding. Been broken for a while for me.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've updated my answer with a cause of this issue on at least my machine. Hopefully you can get this into the right hands!

Answer (score 3):

What I see:

[image]

Comment: just upgraded from chrome 61->62.0.3202.94 , I see bold

Comment: I'm on the same version, and don't see any **bold** on posts. Maybe it's a style issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Chrome, version `62.0.3202.94` on Mac OSX, Version 10.11.6, and I don't see **bold** when it's properly formatted in markdown.

This is an issue for me- I've actually been editing other people's posts thinking that they were trying to use *italic* formatting, which renders fine. It's been going on for at least a few days without me really noticing what was going on.

I am able to get **bold** to display on stackoverflow.com, and another child site (code review), but not on this meta or the main site.

I've attached a screenshot of what I see below.

---

> [image]

---

I got really sick of dealing with this while editing posts, so I took a look under the hood to see if I could figure out what was causing this. Looks like its due to a font issue, specifically, 'PT Sans', the default font in my styles. Removing this style from the `font-family` attribute for the page causes bold to render for my browser.

These are the five fonts used:

- 'PT Sans' - fails to render bold
- 'Helvetica Neue' - renders bold
- Helvetica - renders bold
- Arial - renders bold
- Sans-serif - renders bold

To make matters weirder, the examples on the [google fonts page](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/PT+Sans) displays the bold without any problems. Still occuring as of 3-6-18.

Comment: Glad I am not the only one experiencing this issue. I too am on Mac OSX (10.11.3) with Chrome build 62.0.3202.94.

Comment: I'm on windows 10, maybe this is specific to MAC OSX ?

Comment: Seems like it, and this issue is still affecting me.

Comment: I had the same issue on Firefox a while ago and I raised a bug with Stackexchange - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302327/bold-not-rendering-correctly-on-firefox

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem on OSX 10.13.3, Chrome Version 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit).

It looks like this only does not affect code block text.

source:

```
### h3 with **strong** and *em* and `pre` and ***em strong*** **`strong pre`** ***`strong em pre`***

text with **strong** and *em* and `pre` and ***em strong*** **`strong pre`** ***`strong em pre`***
```

your machine:

#### h3 with **strong** and *em* and `pre` and ***em strong*** **`strong pre`** ***`strong em pre`***

text with **strong** and *em* and `pre` and ***em strong*** **`strong pre`** ***`strong em pre`***

my machine:

[image]